# can this mysql query be optimized further?

Tags: mysql, optimization, profiler, group-by

I have this query

```
select counterparty_id, 
       max(id) max_id 
from client_administrations 
where counterparty_type = 1 
  and effective_on <= '2013-10-22' 
group by counterparty_id
```

When I explain this query it gives me

> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>              id: 1
>     select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: client_administrations
>            type: index
>   possible_keys: NULL
>             key: cec
>         key_len: 11
>             ref: NULL
>            rows: 234969
>           Extra: Using where; Using index
>   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

this query returns 2,34,630 rows which takes 0.18 seconds to run. But the problem is this query is used many times in a given functionality and the rows in the database might go upto a million even. That is my concern. I tried profiling for this

> mysql> show profile for query 1;
>   +----------------------+----------+
>   | Status               | Duration |
>   +----------------------+----------+
>   | starting             | 0.000126 |
>   | checking permissions | 0.000018 |
>   | Opening tables       | 0.000032 |
>   | System lock          | 0.000016 |
>   | init                 | 0.000051 |
>   | optimizing           | 0.000029 |
>   | statistics           | 0.000145 |
>   | preparing            | 0.000047 |
>   | executing            | 0.000010 |
>   | Sorting result       | 0.000009 |
>   | **Sending data         | 0.117429** |
>   | end                  | 0.000024 |
>   | query end            | 0.000007 |
>   | closing tables       | 0.000012 |
>   | freeing items        | 0.000016 |
>   | logging slow query   | 0.000004 |
>   | cleaning up          | 0.000005 |
>   +----------------------+----------+

This shows sending data takes maximum amount of time. The RAM size in my localhost is 3GB and in server it is 32 GB. EVen this makes no difference in the time taken for query to run. Its not only for this query but there are several queries in my database which inspite of having index in the "extra" column of explain the maximum time is taken in sending data of profiling. I did change some global variables. Here is the default setting of my global variables

> mysql> show variables like "%cache%";
>   +------------------------------+----------------------+
>   | Variable_name                | Value                |
>   +------------------------------+----------------------+
>   | binlog_cache_size            | 32768                |
>   | binlog_stmt_cache_size       | 32768                |
>   | have_query_cache             | YES                  |
>   | key_cache_age_threshold      | 300                  |
>   | key_cache_block_size         | 1024                 |
>   | key_cache_division_limit     | 100                  |
>   | max_binlog_cache_size        | 18446744073709547520 |
>   | max_binlog_stmt_cache_size   | 18446744073709547520 |
>   | metadata_locks_cache_size    | 1024                 |
>   | query_cache_limit            | 1048576              |
>   | query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096                 |
>   | query_cache_size             | 16777216             |
>   | query_cache_type             | ON                   |
>   | query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF                  |
>   | stored_program_cache         | 256                  |
>   | table_definition_cache       | 400                  |
>   | table_open_cache             | 400                  |
>   | thread_cache_size            | 8                    |
>   +------------------------------+----------------------+

Can something be done to help this "sending data " part.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:-

Added show create table client_administrations

```
client_administrations | CREATE TABLE `client_administrations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `counterparty_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `counterparty_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `administered_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `registered_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `effective_on` date NOT NULL,
  `performed_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recorded_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-01-06 14:29:13',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cec` (`counterparty_id`,`counterparty_type`,`effective_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=234635 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE client_administrations;` and add the output in the question, please.

Comment: Just added it. Please check

Comment: Does the query return as many rows as the table have (around 234630)? If so, that indicates that the `counterparty_id` could have a `UNIQUE` constraint - and then you could remove the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This scenario has a such that it is unique right now. But actually a counterparty_id can have many ids ...id is auto-increment. Basically using this query we are getting max(id) for each counterparty_id

Comment: I would use a `(counterparty_type, counterparty_id, effective_on)` I don't expect it to be much more efficient with the current data (it seems all the rows have `counterparty_type=1` now) but it's better index for your query.

Comment: Tried this gives same results

Comment: Well, grouping, checking and sending 200K rows of data requires some time. 0.18 seconds seems reasonable. The **"sending"** is a bit misleading. It doesn't mean that all that time is spent on sending the data but retrieving it as well.